# Colorize orthochromatic print with Gimp

Tags: gimp, colorization

I've just started working with Gimp, and I would eventually like to try my hand at colorization. One photo I would like to do is of my father and mother from circa 1943. He is in his uniform, and his unit patch (63rd Infantry, "Blood and Flame") can be seen. However, it appears that the picture was taken on orthochromatic film, because what would be red shows up as a deep black. The same is true for the lipstick my mother is wearing. How can I make these appear as appropriate shades of red? Simply adding a red layer doesn't work, since it is swallowed up by the black.

UPDATE:  Here is a picture of the patch from Wikipedia:
[image]

And here is a small section of my photo showing the patch:
[image]

You can see how the old film renders the red as a deep black.

Comment: Nothing in the dark areas looks like the flames of the patch, so trying to colorize that area is hopeless IMHO, but grafting a patch using the image above could be doable. But before you attempt colorization, this image requires some very serious clean-up.

Comment: Thanks, @xenoid.  I agree with the serious clean-up, and that is my first objective with this particular picture.  As to the patch, I would say that the edge is OD green, as is the curved line going through the black region.  The light region toward the back of the patch appears to be the sword.  As I said, the use of ortho film makes anything red appear black.  You are probably right about grafting in the patch, but I was hoping to avoid things that would have to be totally hand-drawn.

Comment: Correction on that last sentence:  "You are probably right about grafting in the patch, but I will have to investigate how to properly scale and rotate."

Answer (score 0):

All depends how you colorize, and nothing says that you have to use the same method on the whole picture. You can extract parts to their own layer (and possibly layer groups if your colorization involves layers), so that they appear above the general image.

Answer (score -3):

Colorization aside, I don't think that's the same patch.

[image: Patch]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/70957)

Comment: @Kai Mattern - Agreed, but the comment required an **image**.

Comment: It could be the same patch.  There is a fold so only part of it is visible.  The lighter bar could be the sword running along the fold.

Comment: @xiota - The outer flame pattern is radically diiferent to me.

Comment: It was shot on orthochromatic film, so the colors of the flame and surrounding patch may not separate well.  Plus, it appears to be an out-of-focus area that's been over processed.

Comment: Given the amount of generational loss involved in getting the picture on your screen (photograph onto film, print film, store print for 80 years, scan print), it's not surprising that some detail has been been lost.  The patch, being embroidered rather than printed, probably wasn't as high-resolution as Wikipedia's drawing to begin with.